# java check for zero with different decimals

Tags: java

I need to check if a value taken from database (string) is zero (with any decimal).
Following are the few samples

```
0.000 - true   
0 - true  
0.000000 - true  
0.0000000000 - true  
0.0000000001 - false  
0.10 - false
```

Can anyone please tell any simple way to check the above?

Comment: `str.matches("0+(\\.0*)?")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different ways to do that. The first question is, why are you retrieving this value as a `String` in the first place and not as a `BigDecimal`?

To check the value against 0, you could do:

```
if (new BigDecimal(string).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0) {
    // the String is 0, whatever its scale
}
```

`compareTo` doesn't take the scale of the decimal into account. This, however, will run into memory concern is the String is really big.

Another completely different way would be to use a regular expression, like @khelwood commented.

Comment: I'd add +2 for both 1. asking why string and 2. using compareTo. But I can only +1 :p

Answer (score 1):

Consider matching your string against the regular expression `0([.]0+)?`. Use `String#matches` to do that.

Note that this requires exactly one zero before any decimal point.

I'm normally reluctant to use a regular expression to compare numeric quantities, but I think an exception can be made here. This is chiefly because (i) you already have a string, (ii) a floating point type may be of insufficient size to parse the number accurately, and (iii) a big decimal type will perform an unnecessary parse and comparison.

Bear in mind that some locales use `,` for the decimal point, and my solution also doesn't support a signed zero.

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest way would be:

```
           String s ="0.0001";
           char c1 ='0'; 
           char c2 ='.';
           boolean result = true;
           int cnt =0;
            for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
               if(s.charAt(i)!=c1 || s.charAt(i)!=c2 ){
                 result = false;
                }
              }
           if(result == true)
             system.out.println("input is zero");
            else
             system.out.println("input is non-zero");
```